# Affine Transformation using Forward Warping

Tags: python, image-processing, nearest-neighbor

I am writing function that applies affine transformation to the input image.My function, first finds the six affine transformation parameters with size is 6x1.The function then applies these parameters to all image coordinates.The new coordinates I obtained have a float value. To create a new image from these coordinates, I converted the new coordinates to integers. I made the color assignment for the new image as follows:
Let's say input image coordinate is equal (i,j) and digital number value is this pixsel is equal (0,0,0) and  (i,j) refers to (m,k) in the output image.Then,I say digital value of (m,k) is equal (0,0,0).

I searched forward warping and I didn't understand a topic.As I said before,I converted the new coordinates float to integers.Can this be done in forward warping?

Please help me...

Comment: 2) you have to do it in the other way: go through the pixels of the output image and using the inverse transformation get a pixel from the source image. This way you won't have empty holes - of course you can still have pixels which would try to get data from outside of the input image and you will have to leave them empty.

Comment: Firstly thank you so much for answer.So would it be wrong to leave it as I described?Because in the next step, I will apply bilinear interpolation.

Comment: Bilinear interpolation uses the same inverse transformation described by @tevemadar.

Comment: Forward warping still needs to apply backward warping locally, it is just an optimization to avoid having to buffer the entire source image. Just imagine the case that you want to "warp" an 1x1 image to an 1x2 rectangle. Whatever is done, transforming a single input pixel coordinate "0,0" obviously can't result in target coordinates "0,0" *and* "1,0" at the same time. If you have the entire image in the memory anyway, just don't bother with forward warping.

Comment: Thank you @tevemadar.I use two method first one is forward warping and I didn't apply backward warping again and my output image has  missing pixels.Other method is inverse warping and I use nearest neighbor interpolation for fixed missing pixel.Then I compare this output images.